# Spark dataframe process partitions in batches, N partitions at a time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to process Spark dataframe partitions in batches, N partitions at a time. For example if i have 1000 partitions in hive table, i need to process 100 partitions at a time.

I tried following approach

1. Get partition list from hive table and find total count
2. Get loop count using total_count/100
3. Then

   ```
    for x in range(loop_count):
        files_list=partition_path_list[start_index:end_index]            
        df = spark.read.option("basePath", target_table_location).parquet(*files_list)
   ```

But this is not working as expected. Can anyone suggest a better method. Solution in Spark Scala is preferred

Comment: Could you elaborate on `But this is not working as expected`? what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: start_index and end_index is not incrementing correctly and I am not sure whether for loop is processed sequential in spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop you have is just having `x` increment each time. That's why the start and end indices do not increment.

Not sure why you mention Scala since your code is in Python.
Here's an example with loop count being 1000.

```py
partitions_per_iteration = 100
loop_count = 1000
for start_index in range(0, loop_count, partitions_per_iteration):
    files_list=partition_path_list[start_index:start_index + partitions_per_iteration]
    df = spark.read.option("basePath", target_table_location).parquet(*files_list)
```

In Scala, you can do a similar loop:

```scala
total = 1000
for {
    startIndex <- 0 until total by 100
} {
    val filesList = partitionsPathList.slice(startIndex, startIndex + partitionsPerIteration)
    val df = ...
}
```

I think `total` or `totalPartitions` is a clearer variable name than "loop count".

Comment: I am testing this code. I asked for Scala because i am migrating from Pyspark to Scala